# Как зациклить обычный массив в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Имею этот код, но выдает несоответствие типов в цикле, когда в dl заношу массив. Как правильно, подскажите пожалуйста, завтра лабу сдать нужно ...

```
prg segment para public 'code'
assume cs:prg,ss:prg,es:prg,ds:prg
org 100h
mas dw, 41h,4Dh,38h,32h
start: jmp go
go:
mov ax, 0600h
mov bh,07
mov cx, 0000
mov dx,184fh
mov cx,5

Zero:
mov dl,mas 
int 21h
loop Zero
ret
prg ends
end start
```

Comment: Хочу вас огорчить, у вас и логика программы не верна

Comment: @Madnestranger, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. После `dw` не нужна запятая.
2. Если вы элемент массива заносите в `dl` (байтовый регистр), то массив должен быть байтовый, т.е. вместо `dw` должно быть `db` (конечно можно и из массива слов можно побайтно читать, но не буду перегружать информацией).
3. `start: jmp go` должно быть выше `mas db ...`, т.к. вам нужно "перепрыгнуть" через массив.
4. `mov dl, mas` каждый раз в цикле заносит первый элемент массива в регистр. Весь массив в регистр занести невозможно. Вместо этого нужно что-то вроде `mov dl, ds:[mas+di]`, `di` до цикла инициализировать нулем, и в цикле увеличивать на 1.
5. Не уверен в правильности вывода на экран с помощью `int 21h`, но разбираться лень.